Reference request scale anomaly
Can anyone recommend some books, notes and review-oriented papers on scale anomaly, with a view towards its relation to renormalization? Such as an anomaly perspective on RG, Callan-Symanzik equations etc?
I only know of one paper by Coleman on "Why dilatation generators do not generate dilatations."
